# Why the buildozer directory is not being created?

Tags: buildozer

I'm installing Buildozer on my Ubuntu machine and after
running `buildozer init` I could find the `buildozer.spec` file but I should be able
to find `.buildozer` directory as well but the directory wasn't created.
I looked for it with `ls -al` because I know the directory is hidden.

In the spec file I found line that reads:
`build_dir = ./.buildozer` which seems correct to me

I installed the latest release. Is it being created elsewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory was created after running `buildozer -V` but it should be clearly
described in the docs somewhere.